# is there a single page that lists all css properties with their default values?

Tags: css

Every reference that I'm looking at like http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference has every property on its own page and then I must scrape the website to get all the data.

What I need is a table with for example this format:

```
 css_prop_name       | default_value
-------------------------------
 font-weight         | normal
 background-position | 0% 0%
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be useful. It has all the default values for the CSS properties.

**http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html**